# Training word2vec model

Tags: nlp, data-science, word2vec

How to train the Google's pre-trained model Word2Vec model(googlenews-negative 300) with new words? I have a corpus of new medical terms but their word vectors aren't present in the model given by google. So, how to train new words in word2vec model?

Comment: Assuming you have enough text to train a model with these novel & domain-important words, why do you want to extend that old model? It's based on a private Google dataset of news articles from no later than 2013, and uses a bunch of preprocessing that's not been fully described. Is there some special reason to think you need those words, trained on that old & different-domain text, for some current-day need? (Even any medical terms in those vectors are likely to be dominated to layperson/mass-media word senses, rather than medical-expert word-senses.)

Comment: the medical words that I have are not in its vocab, like if I have a Term Dentist Consultation, and I want to compare it with Dentist Advice, so if I add these 2 in the word2vec vocab I can do a similarity check on these words too.

Comment: But let's say you have a large enough text corpus to train *your* words, and you have figured out the right tokenization, preprocessing, & phrase-combinations (like "Dentist_Consultation") for *your* needs. You can just train your own word-vectors. Why do you expect some other 8+ year-old word-vectors, where the words come from general news articles, will be helpful? Do you have some theory why that's necessary? Did you see some other writeup that claimed or demonstrated that re-using those old vectors is a worthwhile idea?

Comment: I have less data so i can't train my own word vectors. What i did is i made my own word vectors of the medical terms using intersect function of word2vec format and then i started comparing it with terms already in the word2vec vocab, so is that the right approach?

Comment: Also i want my word vectors to be made on basis of context, how could i make word vectors based on context on my own without using word2vec.

Comment: Unfortunately, if your data is minimal, even good word-vectors for your new words may be out of reach. Word2Vec needs many varied usage examples of all relevant words to train the word-vectors into useful positions. Can you get more data to interleave into your training, perhaps even from public sources? `intersect_word2vec_format()` is at-best an experimental feature that could be useful for affecting vector-initialization before doing lots of training. Without seeing your code, I can't be sure if your usage is appropriate, but if you're intersecting-then-immediately-comparing, probably not.

Comment: While there are other algorithms related to word2vec, or that otherwise create word-vectors, all that I know of require just as much example-usage training-data or more.

Comment: Okay, thanks. My issue is solved now.